# "Only to" vs "Just to"

Tags: vocabulary

In the following sentence I have to write one word:

> One annoying example of this is when you walk into a room, _____ to
>   realise you have forgotten what your reason for going there was.

According to the key, it is **only**. But why doesn't **just** work? No dictionaries have evidence for this phrase. The only reliable source was [ludwig.guru](https://ludwig.guru/s/just+to+realise), which suggests both work. Would you accept my answer?

Comment: They both work for me, but "only" feels more natural/idiomatic.

Comment: You say, "No dictionaries have evidence for this phrase". Which phrase could you not find in dictionaries: "only ..." or "just ...".?  I haven't come across your "reliable source" before: on what grounds do you consider it 'reliable'? Some of the highlighted sentences there sound 'odd' or 'strange' to me.

Comment: To me "just" sounds odd.  I agree with @JamesRandom that "only" feels more natural/idiomatic.

Comment: Perhaps "just" sounds natural to me because I am not a native speaker and literally translated, both make perfect sense. I guess what I needed to here is that "just" is not idiomatic and sounds awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these two sentences:

> 1. *I walked into the room **only** to see whether the window was open.*
> 2. *I walked into the room **only** to realise I had forgotten my reason for going there.*

In the first sentence '***only***' has the sense of

> Solely, merely, exclusively; with no one or nothing more besides; as a single or solitary thing or fact; no more than. Also, with a verb or verb phrase: no more than, simply, merely (OED).

In this context '*just*' works as well as 'only'.

In the second sentence '***only***' serves to

> emphasize the contrary nature of a consequence (OED).  For example

*Should I stay..at home, I would only dissipate my little fortune.* R. Burns (1787) Let. to J. Smith 11 June

or the OP example.

In this 2nd sentence '*just*' is not an alternative because it does not have this meaning.